# $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ roots of $f$ with $f'(x_{1}) \gt 0$ and $f'(x_{2}) \gt 0$. Existence of another root between $(x_{1},x_{2})$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

I'm struggling with this question. I tried proving by contradiction but I don't know if I'm doing it right. Any help is highly appreciated!

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth such as $f'(x_{1}) \gt 0$ and $f'(x_{2}) \gt 0$ for $x_{1} \lt x_{2}$ roots of $f$. Show that $f$ has at least one root in $(x_{1},x_{2})$.

My atempt:

By Rolle's Theorem, $\exists c \in (x_{1},x_{2}):f'(c)=0$, therefore, $f(c) \gt 0$.

Suppose by contradiction that $\nexists k \in (x_{1},x_{2}):f(k)=0.$ Therefore, $\forall x \in (c,x_{2}), f'(x) \lt 0$.

Since $f$ is smooth, $f'$ is continuous. So, $\exists \delta \gt 0: f'(y) \gt 0, \forall y \in (x_{2}-\delta,x_{2}+\delta)$. Let $y=x_{2}-\frac{\delta}{2}$. Since $y \in (c,x_{2}) \implies f'(y) \lt 0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, since there is no way you can deduce that $f(c)>0$.

Since $f(x_1)=0$ and $f'(x_1)>0$, there is some number $y_1$ in $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(y_1)>0$. And since $f(x_2)=0$ and $f'(x_2)>0$, there is some number $y_2$ in $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(y_2)<0$. But then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $y$ berween $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $f(y)=0$. And, sonce both $y_1$ and $y_2$ belong to $(x_1,x_2)$, so does $y$.

Comment: In fact, for some $\delta > 0$, then for *every* $y_1 \in (x_1, x_1 + \delta)$, then $f(y_1) > 0$; and similarly near $x_2$.

Comment: Why can't we deduce that $f(c) \gt 0$? I mean, since $f'(x_{1}) \gt 0$ and $f'(c)=0$ and $c \in (x_{1},x_{2})$, $c$ must be a local maximum, isn't that right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndréCordeiroValério Note that $\sin'(0),\sin'(2\pi)>0$. However, $\sin'\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)=0$ and $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)<0$.